# Does anyone understand the SlideMaster property of the Powerpoint Presentation object?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, object-model

I refer specifically to the 2016 version, but this should also apply to 2013 and 2010.

----- TLDR Summary

- Is it possible to use VBA to add a new Slide Master using a method
  that I haven't found?
- Is it possible to use VBA to access or manipulate the Layouts of
  Slide Masters other than the first one in a Presentation object?
- I suspect that the answer to both is "No" and that MS has merely
  screwed up the exposure of the underlying objects, but others may
  know more about programming PPT than me.

------ The Whole Question

Microsoft has deemed PowerPoint unworthy of a macro recorder for lo these many versions (I think it was dropped in either 2003 or 2007 from memory), so no help can be obtained from there.

The linked MSDN "help" [item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff745484.aspx) is woeful. It states that the property returns a Master object, though that isn't relevant for the moment.

An Office support page describes a slide master [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-a-slide-master-b9abb2a0-7aef-4257-a14e-4329c904da54). A Slide Master seems to be where the presentation's Slide Layouts live, presumably in the SlideMaster's CustomLayouts property, though it's interesting to note that only the first 9 of those CustomLayouts correspond to what you see in the GUI. (I count 11 CustomLayout objects in the SlideMaster in a new, blank presentation.) The numbers change if you add new layouts though the two vertical text layouts never seem to appear in the GUI list. This too is not the problem.

The problem is that you can in fact have more than one Slide Master per presentation by going to the View menu, Slide Master, and then selecting Insert Slide Master. Having multiple Slide Masters is discussed on the Office Support site [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-multiple-slide-masters-in-one-presentation-09174b1b-04a3-41b8-bc22-2e21636d9e7f).

Frankly I regard this functionality as slightly broken because if you do that, then apply a Theme to the new Slide Master, you end up with a ***third*** Slide Master; the original under "Office Theme", a second under "Custom Design", and a third under the name of the Theme that you applied. This too is not in itself a problem. (Though it's worth noting that a Presentation does not have an AddSlideMaster method, which means that it does not seem to be possible to do this by VBA. Not that you necessarily ***want*** to, but if you did, you can't. There is only an .AddTitleMaster method which seems to be useless since all presentations have a TitleMaster as far as I can see and if a presentation has one then that method will error out according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._presentation.addtitlemaster(v=office.14).aspx).)

The problem is that the Presentation object does not have a ***collection*** of Slide Masters. It has only that one property, SlideMaster, which returns a single Slide Master / Master object.

Accordingly I can't see any way that you can programmatically add a new Slide Master. And even if you used one that is added through the GUI you can't seem to ***access*** any Slide Master except for the first one. And therefore you don't seem to be able to access, manipulate or assign any Layout from any Slide Master other than the first one to an individual slide.

Am I correct in this assumption, or am I missing something?

I shall offer thanks in advance even though that is often deleted from questions. Not that this one is likely to attract much attention; I suspect that there may be another Tumbleweed badge in my future.

Comment: This is a genuine question and shows research effort. Shouldn't have been downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this page will be helpful in understanding it better - http://skp.mvps.org/2007/ppt003.htm

Comment: Bingo. It's not on that page but on a page that it links to; this one: http://skp.mvps.org/designs.htm Naturally; you insert a new Slide Master so it makes sense for MS to call them "Designs" (eyeroll). Many thanks, you have demystified it greatly.

Comment: Microsoft's terminology in this area of PowerPoint is quite frankly a mess! The UI refers to Slide Master in the View tab and Designs elsewhere. Once in slide master view there are multiple masters each of which contain a 'parent' (no one seems to know what to call it!) and one or more Custom Layouts. I think it probably went off the rails when multiple masters were introduced and backwards compatibility had to be retained.

Comment: @JamieG; yes, I was thinking the same thing. It wouldn't be so bad if the hierarchy was better explained in the CustomLayouts documentation on MSDN, but as of the time of writing it's not explained at all. ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745764.aspx ) It seems that you can manipulate CustomLayout objects in the same way via either the Presentation's SlideMaster object OR a Design's SlideMaster object... BUT first you have to know that the Design object (a) exists and (b) actually means "what we call a slide master when you add it in the GUI".